# How to move all partitions - with single command?

Tags: partitioning

Is there a Linux command to move - not resize - all device partitions ?

I have many test / experimental partitions and like to move them
around (left?) to eliminate empty spaces between them.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Add this information to your question.

Comment: parted: https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html It is a big manual. and no it will not be 1 command but a chain of commands

Comment: Be sure to have good backups. Any move left is a bit more dangerous as any power failure in the middle totally corrupts that partition. Best not to queue the changes but run one at a time to confirm correct completing before starting another change.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: I am not native engklush seaakerm so if this is too harsh - exusme for living,,,Did anybody actually read my post ?

Comment: How  do I edit comment I just posted ? And why is my post marked negative when  nobody actually responded to the subject ? ( Am I wasting  my time here ? )Are the "answers" / suggestion to edit my question created by AI ? I will edit IF somebody WILL ACTUALLY  reAD IT. tHAT IS FAIR

Comment: I am not native English speaker so if this is too harsh - excuse me for living and I am saying  it the simple / direct way I feel  ,,,Did anybody actually read my post ?

Comment: parted: gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html It is a big manual. and no it will not be 1 command but a chain of commands – 
Rinzwind
yesterday sorry I was not expecting RTFM - but I did and it did not   answer my post queestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're best off booting from a live cd and using gparted. Download the gparted live cd
You will have problems doing it while booted from it